# Getting unauthorised access token response in docusign transaction rooms API

Tags: docusignapi

Create access token using the API
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token

Invoke create room API using access token from step 1 
https://stage.cartavi.com/restapi/v1/rooms

Response: "message": "Unauthorized access token "

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Authorization Code Grant as documented here, [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html)

But above link is very specific to ESign and it needs some tweaking for DTR. And you can create access token for that user only who has an ESign account and both DTR and ESign accounts are linked to each other. Also DTR feature should be enabled for the linked ESign account by DocuSign Account Manager from the backend. Please contact your DocuSign Account Manager or Account Executive and request them to connect with DTR Technical Consultant related to DTR APIs.